# Bootstrap css issue with table and glyphicon etc

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got a trouble with bootstrap css design. When I use bootstrap.min.css in my website. Some classes are working and some classes don't. For example, `glyphicon glyphicon-date` won't show up. And another `glyphicon glyphicon-add` is working fine. Another example is table class.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>asda</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>asds</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>asds</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>asds</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is striped didn't working on me. I attached local bootstrap css file and online css link. But still it is not working. What's wrong with this? How can I fix this?

Comment: You want icons it might be easier to try font-awesome instead of debugging this. bower install components-font-awesome --save     here is there page http://fontawesome.io/

Comment: But why bootstrap style won't applied? Do u know about this?

Comment: did you load the js file of the boostrap? https://jsfiddle.net/rute797p/
for the glyphicon, did you put the glyphicon fonts style within your application?

Comment: Yes, i did. Didn't work

Comment: if you can reproduce this with jsfiddle or codepen we can help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ARLEQUINA/k9g0hkqk/ here is the code.

Comment: Here is screen of my table http://i68.tinypic.com/14930vn.jpg

Comment: It is working absolutely fine and I do not see any errors. The example of your code in the question is working as well. What outcome do your want to see?

Comment: http://i68.tinypic.com/14930vn.jpg  here is screenshot of mine.

Comment: Striped doesn't work,

Comment: You have an empty row `<tr>`. please try to remove the it. https://jsfiddle.net/k9g0hkqk/1/

Comment: Don't include css file twice. just use the online link or the local file.